Position of ion charges
I want to write the equilibrium equation of ethanoic acid in water using the chemmacro package.
By wanting to add the phases, I do not obtain the expected result.
With
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{CH3COOH\aq + H2O\lqd{} <=> H3O+ + CH3COO-\aq }

\end{document}

I obtain

With,
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{CH3COOH\aq + H2O\lqd{} <=> CH3COO-\aq + H3O+}

\end{document}


Another exemple :
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

\ch{Ag+\aq + Cl-\aq <=> AgCl\sld{}}

\end{document}


I think that for all these equations the problem is similar but I don't see how I can make it all clean

Something like this? If so, you missed almost all {}, which are vital for macro-processing.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}

\begin{document}

    \ch{CH3COOH\aq{} + H2O\lqd{} 
        <=>
        H3O\pch{} + CH3COO\mch{}\aq{} }

\end{document}


